# How do i remove "Website" field from Wordpress comments

Tags: comments

i have two websites i use Wordpress comments on one website and jetpack comments on another. Both websites shows website column, how do i remove it to save my site from giving unwanted backlinks ?

Comment: Are you talking about the website "field" ?

Comment: Yes, because a lot of spammers use that field to obtain backlinks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Using Plugins to disable Website field from comments**

There are many plugins available in the WordPress repository that remove the Website field from the blog comments.

The most easy way is to install Remove Fields or Remove Comment Website/URL Box.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-fields/

**2. Editing the WordPress Files to remove the Website field from comments**

Open functions.php file and add code.

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'website_remove');
function website_remove($fields)
{
   if(isset($fields['url']))
   unset($fields['url']);
   return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Can i disable it with CSS ?

Comment: You can hide the field with CSS, but it's still part of the DOM. Using the filter is a better solution (no need for a plugin just for this!) as it remove the field from the DOM rather than just hiding it.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are talking about the website "field". If it is so, add this code in the functions.php file to remove the field:

```
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields', 'remove_website_field');
function remove_website_field($fields){
    if(isset($fields['url']))
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way than this to remove it ?

Comment: This is the best way to remove the field. You can remove it from the core if you really wanted (don't do that), but this is exactly what filters are meant for. Why do you need another method?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 easy ways to do it :

**SIMPLE AND SHORT: EDITING CSS**
Go to customize and then custom css/js and add the following code

```
.comment-form-url{
    display:none;
}
```

**ADD CODE SNIPPET TO FUNCTIONS.PHP**

Go to Appearance > Theme editor and click on functions.php

```
// url field disabler
function remove_url_comments($fields) {
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','remove_url_comments');
```

**USING PLUGINS**

Go to Plugins > Add New and search for any one of the following plugin.
Remove Fields or Remove Comment Website/URL box or disable-hide-comment-URL.

For a full explanation, you can read my blog [here](https://bloglikho.ml/how-to-remove-website-url-field-from-wordpress-comment-form/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as [every](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/328052/5380) [other](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/328035/5380) [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/388877/5380) has mentioned... definitely the preferred WordPress way would be using the [`comment_form_default_fields` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form_default_fields/#comment-2565).

However, it's very conceivable you might have a situation where you need other solutions.  For example, if you're using a default theme and don't want to modify it (because you wouldn't want to lose the changes if the theme gets an update). I've got a site with very few plugins/customizations, but it does have an option for custom CSS/JS. I've used both Javascript and CSS solutions.

This CSS hides it from the page (same as mentioned in [Vinu's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/388877/5380) )

```
form.comment-form .comment-form-url {
    display: none;
}
```

Even better... this JS removes the url field from the page (actually in the weird event there is more than one on a page, this would remove them all):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.comment-form-url').forEach(child => child.parentNode.removeChild(child));
```